# Add custom fields from different posts

Tags: php, custom-field, array

I am trying to add up custom fields from different posts. The array I created is not working.

Here is the code.

```
<?php $totalpricearray = query_posts('post_type=items&author='.$thisauthorID.'&tag='.$thispostID); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

    $productprice = get_post_meta($post->ID, "productprice", true);
    $productquantity = get_post_meta($post->ID, "productquantity", true);
    $totalproductprice = ($productprice * $productquantity);
    echo $totalproductprice, ',';
         endwhile;

         $totalprice = array($totalpricearray);
         echo array_sum($totalprice); ?>
```

Any ideas,

Marvellous

(ps just noticed array is working but equals 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$totalprice_posts = get_posts('post_type=items&author='.$thisauthorID.'&tag='.$thispostID.'&numberposts=-1');
$totalprice_array = array();
foreach ($totalprice_posts as $post) {
    $productprice = get_post_meta($post->ID, "productprice", true);
    $productquantity = get_post_meta($post->ID, "productquantity", true);
    $totalproductprice = ($productprice * $productquantity);
    array_push($totalprice_array, $totalproductprice);
}
echo implode(',', $totalprice_array);
echo array_sum($totalprice_array);
?
```

Comment: Brilliant although its not adding up the last value in the array

Comment: @Robin I Knight: That sounds a bit unlikely...the last two lines are merely PHP core functions. If there were a difference it would be a bug in PHP, unless there's a type casting problem with the values.

Comment: I checked and found no explanation for it. Yet when I changed get_posts to query_posts it did add the last value.

Comment: @Robin I Knight FYI I rejected your edit because `query_posts()` should never be used for secondary loops. I am not sure why results between two function might differ in your case, but switching to query post will likely cause more issues than it solves.

Comment: You know more than me I'm not arguing. Looking at it furhter though, if by secondary loop do you mean a loop within a loop, because it isn't. There are in fact 2 other loops above it one containing the page (post_type=bookings) and the other containing items (post_type=items). Both of these loops have come to their conclusion before the beginning of this one. loop is executed in full above

Comment: @Robin I Knight: I agree with Rarst that it's always a good idea to only use/modify the main loop, if you have to. That is, if you want to use template tags or template parts. In all other cases, it's safer (and probably also a little less 'expensive') to just run over the result of `get_posts();`. Always remember that WP is full of hooks and highly extensible. You never know what comes after you that wants to access the main loop, again.

Comment: Is the quantity always set? if that returns 0, your multiplication(`$totalproductprice`) will fail, price x 0 = 0.

Comment: I have checked the quantity all is correct. I have viewed the source and all is as it should be. I have replaced the item at the last item with another and it didn't add that either. Any ideas? There is an example available here http://www.divethegap.com/update/booking/adventure-training-81/?print

Comment: @Robin I Knight - Try the code i posted into an answer.

Comment: @Robin I Knight: Ahh sorry, my fault...soon as i saw your example i got it...the issue is that get_posts() defaults to fetching only 5 posts. Add `&numberposts=-1` to the parameters and it'll work.

Comment: updated answer accordingly

Comment: Good call, totally didn't think about the posts per page setting.

Comment: @t31os Yepp, me keeps forgetting it all the time, too. It's not the most sensible of defaults (although it can be argued for).